# how to quickly reset all the checkboxes on the webpage?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a div with checkboxes, and everytime before checking any of them I want to make sure they are cleared first. Any input on how I can do it?

The HTML code for the div consisting of checkboxes is

```
<div class="row_bus_groups cuke_business_group">
<div class="row">
<input class="field_checkbox cuke_partners" type="checkbox" id="SelectedBusinessGroups[0]" name="SelectedBusinessGroups[0]" value="Partners">
<label for="SelectedBusinessGroups[0]"><span class="translated_text" rel="BusinessGroups.Partners">Partners</span></label>  
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedBusinessGroups[0]" value="">
</div>                                          
<div class="row">
<input class="field_checkbox cuke_press" type="checkbox" id="SelectedBusinessGroups[1]" name="SelectedBusinessGroups[1]" value="Press">
<label for="SelectedBusinessGroups[1]"><span class="translated_text" rel="BusinessGroups.Press">Press</span></label>  
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedBusinessGroups[1]" value="">
</div>                                          
</div>
```

I tried doing

```
@browser.div(:class, "cuke_business_group").checkbox.each{ |all| all.clear }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close. Try this:

```
@browser.div(:class => "cuke_business_group").checkboxes.each {|checkbox| checkbox.clear}
```